# CORS issue happening in tubesock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a Sinatra application which runs fine.Now to implement websockets I am using tubesock gem and have added following code

```
class Server
  def call(env)
    if env["HTTP_UPGRADE"] == 'websocket'
      tubesock = Tubesock.hijack(env)
      tubesock.onmessage do |message|
        puts "Got #{message}"
      end
      tubesock.listen
      [ -1, {}, [] ]
    else
      [404, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ['Not Found']]
    end
  end
end
```

Now it is giving CORS error(Cross origin error).Previously it was working fine.Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: "Now it is giving CORS error(Cross origin error).Previously it was working fine." – Then the problem is in the changes you made between "previously" and "now".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use rack/cors and resolve the issue